# Switch Statement inside condition refactoring

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I have a piece of code that works but I do not like the way it looks. It looks clunky and messy. Is basically an if statement that has a switch statement inside.

Is there a way to refactor this? Maybe a well know to deal with them?

```
private Direction update(Coordinates coordinate) {
    if (coordinate.isLeft()) {
        switch (coordinate.getDirection()) {
        case NORTH: return Direction.WEST;
        case SOUTH: return Direction.EASTH;
        case EASTH: return Direction.NORTH;
        case WEST: return Direction.SOUTH;
        }
    }
    if (coordinate.isRight()) {
        switch (coordinate.getDirection()) {
        case NORTH: return Direction.EASTH;
        case SOUTH: return Direction.WEST;
        case EASTH: return Direction.SOUTH;
        case WEST: return Direction.NORTH;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This would be on-topic at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your method is missing a return statement.

Comment: Stop vandalizing your question!

Comment: I fixed the return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you order your enum clockwise, you can walk from one to the next with a simple index:

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST;

    public Direction rotate(boolean clockwise) {
        int nextIndex = ordinal() + (clockwise ? 1 : 3);
        return values()[nextIndex % 4];
    }
}
```